# How to solve expo-cli request entity too large?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Every time I start my expo project with `yarn start` I get the following error once my android device tries to upload and launch the app.

```
Android Bundling complete 288ms
AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
    at read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
    at jsonParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:135:5)
    at call (/home/mathieu_auclair/Documents/Coinmiles/repositories/mobile/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/home/mathieu_auclair/Documents/Coinmiles/repositories/mobile/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/middleware/remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware.ts:31:3)
    at call (/home/mathieu_auclair/Documents/Coinmiles/repositories/mobile/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/home/mathieu_auclair/Documents/Coinmiles/repositories/mobile/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at serveStatic (/home/mathieu_auclair/Documents/Coinmiles/repositories/mobile/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
› Stopped server
Done in 378.28s.
```

I tried both upgrading/downgrading my version of expo-cli, but to no avail. This issue is occurring since we migrated to eas build system for expo.

What's the solution to avoid android throwing an exception `entity too large` when transferring the build to the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/3896), you may manually fix the package responsible for the crash.
Open the following file in your favorite file editor with `sudo`

```
sudo vim /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js
```

Then look for the function declaration of `readStream` where you'll override the limit value for either a custom value or `null` for no limit.

```js
function readStream (stream, encoding, length, limit, callback) {
  var complete = false
  var sync = true

  limit = null; // Set custom limit for all payload

  // check the length and limit options.
  // note: we intentionally leave the stream paused,
  // so users should handle the stream themselves.
  if (limit !== null && length !== null && length > limit) {
    return done(createError(413, 'request entity too large', {
      expected: length,
      length: length,
      limit: limit,
      type: 'entity.too.large'
    }))
  }

  //...
}
```

With that being said, this is only a workaround, and a better solution should be proposed.

Comment: Do you know the path for MacOS?

Comment: Use the following command to figure out your path with any OS `npm root -g`, consider upvoting ;)

Comment: @Myzel394 a long time later... you can find the path of the library in the error stack trace -> `at readStream (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)`